# Java8 Stream - HashSet of Byte from IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to create a `HashSet<Byte>` of `byte`s `1, 2, 3, ... 9` with the Java 8 Streams API. I thought using `IntStream` and then downgrading the values to `byte` would do it.

I'm trying variations of

`HashSet<Byte> nums = IntStream.range(1, 10).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

`HashSet<Byte> nums = IntStream.range(1, 10).map(e -> ((byte) e)).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

But none of those work.

```
Error:(34, 73) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Do I need to do `flatMap` or `mapToObject`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use mapToObj since HashSet and all generics require Objects

```
Set<Byte> nums = IntStream.range(1, 10)
    .mapToObj(e -> (byte) e)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that one. `Error:(35, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Set<java.lang.Byte>
    upper bounds: java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Byte>,java.lang.Object`

Comment: Works fine if you remove "Hash", i.e. change `HashSet` to `Set`. Answer edited to reflect that.

Comment: The `Set` behind the scenes hopefully isn't a `TreeSet` right? I am relying on that set being able to `get` and `put` at `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: @Hatefiend, if you care so much, use `toCollection(HashSet::new)`.

Comment: @Hatefiend: the `Set` interface has neither, `get` nor `put`, but besides that, I have the strong feeling, you don’t really know what `O(1)` vs. `O(log(n))` means, if you try to discuss that at a `Set` containing *ten* elements and not being able to contain more than 256 elements in general…

Comment: @Holger A TreeSet's `insert` operation takes `O(log(n))` time. A HashSet's `insert` operation takes `O(1)` time. If the `toSet()` function places the elements inside a `TreeSet` then each `insert` call (to fill up the `TreeSet` with elements) will take `O(log(n))` time. I would like this entire operation to take only `O(n)` time.

Comment: @Hatefiend: the `O(…)` notation only tells you, how an algorithm *scales* with very large *n* values. For an arbitrary single *n*, as well as small *n* values in general, an `O(n)` algorithm might be faster than an `O(1)` algorithm, as `O(1)` only tells you that the time taken won’t raise, when *n* becomes very large, not that the time taken will be short. Since in your case, *n* is *very small* and it’s even impossible to ever have more than 256 values, the `O(…)` notation is meaningless. By the way, the `Set` returned by `Collectors.toSet()` is not guaranteed to be mutable at all…

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `MutableByteSet` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) with the `IntStream` and avoid the boxing.

```
ByteSet byteSet = IntStream.range(1, 10)
        .collect(ByteSets.mutable::empty,
                (set, i) -> set.add((byte) i),
                MutableByteSet::addAll);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections